# Exporting CSV with different data

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm attempting to extract licencing information via o365 with the current script:

```
Foreach($User in $Users){

$UPN = $User.UserPrincipalName
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "$UPN" | Select-Object DisplayName,Licenses | Export-Csv -Append -Path c:\test\$exportpath.csv -NoTypeInformation 

}
```

I'm noticing I'm getting two different outputs, whenever I run this via ISE I'll get the following:

[image]

However, when I look at the exported CSV I get the following:

[image]

So my question is how exactly should I set this up so when I extract information and export it into a CSV that it'll capture all information and not simply state it as a generic list?

Comment: Either join the Licenses in the Select-Object with a calculated property or iterate over them with another foreach to have a separate line for each license.

Comment: @LotPings I feel like the better option is a calculated property, a bit unsure how to tackle this so off to google to have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your license field is actually a list of multiple licenses and you need to 'expand' this out before you export to csv. You should be able to do this with a join function or you can iterate through foreach loop.

```
Get-MsolUser -All | Select-Object office,@{name="licenses";expression={$_.licenses.accountskuid}},userprincipalname | Export-Csv .\licenses.csv -NoTypeInformation
```